# Migrating from Apache Http client legacy to OkHttp

Tags: java, android, apache, okhttp, android-apache-legacy

I'm migrating some code from the Apache HTTP client to OkHttp as the Apache client was deprecated in API 23 and now, in API 29 totally eliminated. In general I'm not having too many problems but there's a line for which I can't find an equivalent:

```
myHttpPost.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(myUser, myPassword), HttpPost));
```

I've debugged this line and it generates a String similar to this one:

> Authorization: Basic
>   RU5YRU5EUkEASDASDQWEQFASkLTk2ZjgtOTASDQWEkMWNkYTA1

Reading about it [in the documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/auth/BasicScheme.html#authenticate(org.apache.http.auth.Credentials,%20org.apache.http.HttpRequest)) I can see that the `authenticate` method:

> Produces an authorization string for the given set of Credentials

And that the `UsernamePasswordCredentials` basically creates that credentials from my user and password but I can't find the equivalent in OkHttp, anyone has faced this problem?

I have managed to find a class [in the OkHttp docs](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Authenticator.html), an `Authenticator`, but I'm not really sure it's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re looking for [Credentials.basic()](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-credentials/).

```
        String credential = Credentials.basic("jesse", "password1");
        return Request.Builder()
            .header("Authorization", credential)
            ...
            .build();
```

Comment: Exactly, Jesse, that's what I was looking for. I've given too much thought to the `Authenticator` class I think. In any case, thank you very much.